# How to pass an argument in a React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I need to pass a couple of arguments in a react query `one of which needs to decided by the user action`

Here is how the query looks so far:

```
const { refetch: likeDislikeProfile } = useQuery(
  ['like_dislike_profile'], 
  () => like_dislike_profile_q(data.userid, <BOOLEAN_ARG>), //  
  { enabled: false }
)
```

Whenever the clicks on a `like/dislike` button, the argument will be `true/false` respectively.

This is further used as a query param in the request : `action?like=false`

How do I achieve this?

#### My approach

- create a local state that changes on button click
- create a side effect (useEffect) method which is triggered when this state changes
- which will further trigger this react query

This approach seems bad, can't think of anything else atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your HTTP request is changing data in the backend, that's the use case for [mutations](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations).

From the [official docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/queries#query-basics)

> A query is a declarative dependency on an asynchronous source of data that is tied to a unique key. A query can be used with any Promise based method (including GET and POST methods) to fetch data from a server. If your method modifies data on the server, we recommend using Mutations instead.

For your use case it should be something like this

```
const updateLike = useMutation((id, bool) => like_dislike_profile_q(id, bool))

// invoke the mutation at any point like this
updateLike.mutate('my-id', true)
```

Read more about mutations on [Tkdodo's blog post on mutations](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I had no idea this existed.